Issue with Unreal Engine 5 Blueprint: Multiple Lamp Instances Not Functioning Independently
I have an issue with Unreal Engine 5. I have created a blueprint of the "actor" class. I set it up so that when the player enters the lamp's sphere, it displays "press E". When the player presses E, I turn the lamp on or off. The problem is that when I place multiple instances of this lamp, only the last one works, and I don't understand why. I would like all the lamps to be independent and function in the same way.




I tried to change the class because previously it was a static mesh. I attempted to create a parent class containing the methods so that the child classes could inherit the methods from the parent class.

I solved my problem by simply casting the character in the third person and using 'enable input' and 'disable input' in the box collision events.
